# Is this legal Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

GHC compiles it without a hitch, but it fails miserably at runtime:

```
many_a x =
    let
        a = 2
    in
        let 
            a = 2*a
        in
            x*a
```

Intuitively, this *shouldn't* work. But yet GHC accepted it.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't legal?

Comment: It's legal, but it doesn't do what you think.

Comment: This kind of misconception is one of the reasons why I generally prefer `where` over `let`...`in`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that's valid Haskell code. The thing is that the `a` in the second `let...in` expression is actually a *new* `a`; it's perfectly permissible to *shadow* existing variables by defining a new variable with the same name. However, it doesn't affect the value of the outer `a`. It's generally considered bad style, however, due to the potential for confusion and mistakes; if you pass `-Wall` to GHC, it'll issue a warning if you do this.

It "fails" at runtime because you've defined `a` to be `2*a`, which results in an infinite loop at runtime. This is due to laziness; basically, `(*)` evaluates both its arguments before multiplying them. Evaluating `2` works fine, of course, but evaluating `a` causes it to go through the same process all over again. The same thing that allows infinite lists (like `ones = 1:ones`) makes this code be an infinite loop.